# Any experiences of installing LinuxStandardBase / LSB on RHEL6?

Tags: redhat

I have some commercial software that's expecting me to install LSB on my RHEL6 (actually SL6) system. The problem is that this computer is meant to be a clean RHEL6 system, so that I can test my own software to confirm that it runs on out-of-the-box RHEL6.

I've got a bad feeling about this, and I thought I'd check here before doing this. Has anyone actually tried installing LSB on RHEL6? Did you have any problems afterwards? I installed LSB on a clean Ubuntu (10.10) system about six months ago, and regretted it (although the only specific problem I saw was that some desktop icons stopped working, although this eventually fixed itself - no idea how/why). I guess I'm basically not keen on having a second libc version hanging around.

Thoughts?

Comment: ... A second libc? What? Where did you hear this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you taking about the redhat-lsb package?
Where are you seeing a second libc?

```
$ rpm -ql redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.el6.x86_64
/bin/redhat_lsb_init
/etc/lsb-release.d
/etc/lsb-release.d/core-4.0-amd64
/etc/lsb-release.d/core-4.0-noarch
/etc/lsb-release.d/graphics-4.0-amd64
/etc/lsb-release.d/graphics-4.0-noarch
/etc/lsb-release.d/printing-4.0-amd64
/etc/lsb-release.d/printing-4.0-noarch
/etc/redhat-lsb
/etc/redhat-lsb/lsb_killproc
/etc/redhat-lsb/lsb_log_message
/etc/redhat-lsb/lsb_pidofproc
/etc/redhat-lsb/lsb_start_daemon
/lib/lsb
/lib/lsb/init-functions
/lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3
/usr/bin/lsb_release
/usr/lib/lsb
/usr/lib/lsb/install_initd
/usr/lib/lsb/remove_initd
/usr/sbin/redhat_lsb_trigger.x86_64
/usr/share/man/man1/lsb_release.1.gz
```

*Taken from a Scientific Linux 6.0 x86_64 installation.